# How to handle value in indexed field in mongodb during update?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which looks like this:

```
Book
[
{
  _id:ObjectId(1),
  cover: ObjectId(5),
  title: ABC,
  author: Bob
},
{
  _id:ObjectId(2),
  cover: ObjectId(5),
  title: EFG,
  author: John
},
{
  _id:ObjectId(3),
  cover: null,
  title: XYZ,
  author: Mike
}
]
```

As you can see I have the index on the cover field. This index just has cover field

My question is - User may remove that field value from some documents.

Currently I am setting the values for those field to null.

I have concerns of having many null values for that field as I have an index on it.

Should I just remove that field altogether ($unset) from those documents?

Not sure which one is better for performance given my collection may get large.

I can't find enough documentation on this by searching Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically you seem to be talking about having a field in your document that contains a [Manual Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#document-references) to another field in the collection or database. And your concern seems to be about what to do if that *referenced* document is removed from your collection.

As MongoDB itself has no concept of maintaining referential integrity in the sense that relational databases do, how you maintain this sort of information is up to you.

If you want to remove the reference to the document from the `cover` field you may either set it to `null` as you have shown or perhaps use [**$unset**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) to remove the field completely.

I would go for the $unset approach combined with a [sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) given the use case. With the **sparse** option, only the documents that contain the field would be in the index. On size considerations alone with will mean a smaller index size and should also give better performance where the `cover` information is the key for the search.

In either case you probably want to wrap this in your logic when a [**remove**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) is issued, and [**update**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) the "related" documents accordingly.

```
db.collection.remove({ _id: <ObjectId> });
db.collection.update(
    { cover: <ObjectId> },{ $unset: { cover: "" } },
    { upsert: false, multi: true }
)
```

The **multi** option with cause the update in *all* documents that match the query.

Comment: I am not confused. I said exactly what I wanted to say. You seem confused about the problem. You are thinking it wrong way. Please read it again and let me know if you need more clarification. Thank you.

Comment: @kheya My misread of a line or two in your question. Most of the content still applies, with an edit to comment on the index form to use.